# Parse HTML in Java Linearly

Tags: java, html-parsing

Ok what I'm trying to do is  parse something like this <p> Hello <b> World </b> <u> Underlined </u> </p> **linearly**.  

I've searched through the net, and it always gives me a DOM parser, which is not what I need.

I need an output which would be a tree like this:

```
                            p
                           / \ \
                      Hello   b  u
                              |   \
                           World  underlined
```

Basically, I need a to parse html in Java and try to interpret it (display a gui from the html tags).

Thanks.

Comment: Define "linearly". Explain why you think this should be possible. For that matter, explain what you think 'parsing' means. What kind of output are you expecting? What's inadequate or unuseful about getting a DOM object?

Answer (score 0):

You Need to explain what do you mean by Linearly. If you want to parse and get each tag then DOM parser is one of the Option. But for large HTML files the DOM parser is slow. Alternatively you can use SAX parser and create your own parser. Dom parser internally uses SAX parser

Answer (score 0):

Using a SAX parser is probably what you want, because it reads through an input document from start to finish, calling your code for each node it finds.

SAX is an XML parser, and most HTML isn't perfect XML. So to use SAX you need a tool that can handle imperfect input. I suggest [TagSoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/), which is free and Apache-licensed.

Then you write a class which implements [org.xml.sax.ContentHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html). That class will receives callbacks from the SAX parser as the parser reads through your input. It should call methods in your code like this:

```
startElement("p")
characters("Hello")
startElement("b")
characters("World")
endElement("b")
startElement("u")
characters("Underlined")
endElement("u")
endElement("p")
```

*(The actual methods on ContentHandler have a few more parameters, which I left out of the example for simplicity)*